# Word VBA - Eliminate Floating Object Tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a ton of Word documents with somewhat "corrupted" tables.  I've been able to automate most of the repair process, but one issue is still beyond me.

Many of the tables are floating objects - when I show the hidden formatting marks, I see an anchor by the table.  I can't leave the documents like this, I need to make everything inline.

I do have a segment of code that "fixes" this, but I don't think it is a good solution.  By changing the text wrapping from "None" (the default - what I want it to be) to "Around" and back to "None", this gets fixed.  The code is,

```
Selection.Tables(1).Rows.WrapAroundText = True
Selection.Tables(1).Rows.WrapAroundText = False
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this.  Does anyone know of something that will work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have no  idea why flapping the `WrapAroundText` flag solves your problem, VBA has alot of quirks like that.

Automating this method to all of the tables in the document is fairly simple:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i=1 to Len(ActiveDocument.Tables)
  ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Rows.WrapAroundText = True
  ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Rows.WrapAroundText = False
Next i
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you post a sample document for download that is corrupt? Hearing that you found the anchor, the symbol for a new line in Word, I would this is the best way to do it.

Your code seems to look at each table as you select it, or as your code selects it(?).

Add this to your code to fix any potential problem.

```
For Each Table In Selection.Tables
    If Table.Rows.WrapAroundText = True Then
        Table.Rows.WrapAroundText = True
        Table.Rows.WrapAroundText = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi @BlueBerry if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.